# High execution time when a property of type PropertyInfo being set on model in a custom model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Consider the following sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace WebApiApp.Controllers
{
    public class TheModelFields
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [ModelBinder(typeof(TheModelBinder))]
    public class TheModel
    {
        public PropertyInfo PropInfo { get; set; }
        public PropertyInfo FieldPropInfo;
        public object BoxedPropInfo { get; set; }
    }

    enum TestMode
    {
        PropInfo,
        FieldPropInfo,
        BoxedPropInfo
    }

    public class TheModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue("testMode", out var modeStr) && Enum.TryParse(typeof(TestMode), modeStr, true, out var mode))
            {
                var model = new TheModel();
                var propInfo = typeof(TheModelFields).GetProperty("Id");

                switch (mode)
                {
                    case TestMode.PropInfo:
                        model.PropInfo = propInfo;
                        break;
                    case TestMode.FieldPropInfo:
                        model.FieldPropInfo = propInfo;
                        break;
                    case TestMode.BoxedPropInfo:
                        model.BoxedPropInfo = propInfo;
                        break;
                }

                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
                Timer.Stopwatch.Restart();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Timer
    {
        public static Stopwatch Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    }

    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public IActionResult Test([FromQuery]TheModel model)
        {
            Timer.Stopwatch.Stop();
            if (model is null)
                return BadRequest("pass testMode=PropInfo|FieldPropInfo|BoxedPropInfo for test");
            else
                return Ok($"Time: {Timer.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        }
    }
}
```

The class `TheModel` has a custom ModelBinder named `TheModelBinder`.
In this test, `TheModelBinder` decides what property/field to set based on the value of query string parameter named `testMode`.

Using a static Stopwatch, I started measuring the time between the end of model binding and the beginning of the action. Here are the approximate results:

If `testMode == PropInfo` then `TheModelBinder` sets value to a property of type `PropertyInfo` named `PropInfo`.
(This is pretty slow, around 800-1000 ms)

If `testMode == FieldPropInfo` then `TheModelBinder` sets value to a field of type `PropertyInfo` named `PropInfoField`.
(This one takes 0ms)

If `testMode == BoxedPropInfo` then `TheModelBinder` sets value to a property of type object named `BoxedPropInfo`.
(This one takes 0ms too)

**Now the question is: Why the first testMode (setting the `PropInfo` property) increases the execution time (after the model bound successfully) up to 800-1000 milliseconds?**

Tested on asp.net core 2.1 and 2.2 preview2

To test this yourself, you can do `dotnet new webapi` and paste the content of sample to a new file. If you run the app on port `5000`, you can test the execution time using these URLs:

- `http://localhost:5000/test?testMode=propInfo`
- `http://localhost:5000/test?testMode=propInfoField`
- `http://localhost:5000/test?testMode=boxedPropInfo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable debug level logging, and monitor the log closely while refreshing the browser, you can see where the pause happens when using `testMode=propInfo`:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder[26]
      Attempting to validate the bound parameter 'model' of type 'Q53063808.Controllers.TheModel' ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder[27]
      Done attempting to validate the bound parameter 'model' of type 'Q53063808.Controllers.TheModel'.
```

This is the [model validation of the parameter binder](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2.1.3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/ParameterBinder.cs#L248-L258). The model validation is responsible of validating things like the `[Required]` model validation attribute.

In order for the validation to support arbitrary model structures, it will essentially scan the model type recursively and attempt to validate every single property. Since [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netstandard-2.0) is a pretty large type, validating all properties takes some time—even if there is nothing to validate.

Validation however is always based on the *declared model type*, so an `object` property is not scanned. And validation also only applies to properties. That’s why the `PropertyInfo` property is the only case where validation actually takes time. You can also confirm this by adding another type for `MemberInfo` which is a bit smaller than `PropertyInfo`. It will validate a bit faster than the `PropertyInfo` case.

---

You cannot really disable the model validation selectively (e.g. using some `SkipValidation` attribute). However, you can specify from your model binder, that validation should not run for the model. This is done by setting the validation state for it to supress the validation:

```
bindingContext.ValidationState.Add(model, new ValidationStateEntry { SuppressValidation = true });
bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
```

This will skip the validation for the model completely, so the time should drop down to approximately zero as well.

Alternatively, you can also configure MVC to suppress validation for child members when it finds a `PropertyInfo` member in your model type. To do that, you need to add the following configuration to your Startup’s `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // suppress child validation for `PropertyInfo` members
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(
        new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(PropertyInfo)));
});
```

Comment: The logs for ModelBinding doesn't have time themselves, are we sure that's what's happening?

Comment: @ShahriarGholami Yeah, very sure. You can implement and register a custom `IObjectModelValidator` that does nothing and the time in OP’s code is reduced to zero for all cases.